# The cycle does not fully display all the elements

Tags: winforms

I make a grid of buttons as in the calendar, but for some reason not all of them appear

First, I loop through the array, then fill it with elements and display them, and if the loop variable reaches 7 then I lower the rendering of the buttons by 40 pixels to the bottom

It turns out like this

[image]

It should be something like this

[image]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        Button[] January = new Button[31];

        int XMounth = 400;
        int YMounth = 100;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 1; i < January.Length; i++)
            {
                January[i] = new Button
                {
                    Location = new Point(XMounth,YMounth),
                    Size = new Size(30, 30),

                    Text = Convert.ToString(i),
                    BackColor = Color.Orange
                };

                XMounth += 40;


                if(i >= 7)
                {
                    XMounth = 400;
                    YMounth = 140;
                }

                if (i >= 14)
                {
                    XMounth = 400;
                    YMounth = 180;
                }

                if (i >= 21)
                {
                    XMounth = 400;
                    YMounth = 220;
                }

                if (i >= 27)
                {
                    XMounth = 400;
                    YMounth = 260;
                }


                this.Controls.Add(January[i]);
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions like `i >= 7` are true not just once but for every number `>= 7`, so you reset `XMounth` to 400 for every number in the loop for 7 and above.
You can do this once for every specific row-break or just shorten this using modulo:

```
for (int i = 1; i < January.Length; i++)
{
    January[i] = new Button
    {
    ...        
    };

    XMounth += 40;

    if(i % 7 == 0) { XMounth = 400; YMounth += 40; }
    this.Controls.Add(January[i]);  
}
```